# ls() Function output is different between R & RStudio

Tags: r, rstudio

On my system Rstudio is using Machine's default R version. So logically output of `ls()` should be same for both **R** & **Rstudio**,

**IF**

`getwd()` output is same - Checked & found working directory is same

`dir()` output is same - Checked & found both (File Count as well as File Names) are same

`sessionInfo()` output is same **EXCEPT** R has 1 more package in "loaded via a namespace (and not attached):" **scatterplot3d_0.3-36** other 15 packages are same in both R & RStudio

My Working directory has a **.RData** file which is being used by **R**. I was under the impression that **Rstudio** will also load the same **.RData** file because it is working on same directory.

But I have found that `ls()` output is different for **R** & **Rstudio**

So my Questions are

1. How to force Rstudio to load **.RData** file automatically from Working Directory?
2. How to Find the path of **.RData** File currently being used by **Rstudio**?

**I want that RStudio should list down same variables that have been generated in R.**

I am NOT able to modify the Folder Path  to **`~`** so that every time if I change working directory in **`.Rprofile`** Rstudio will take automatically correct location....

Incidentally I have found that **.RData** is being saved by **Rstudio** in my working directory so **R** is using this file correctly but More research is needed by me ;( on **Rstudio**

[image]

EDIT-1: Clarification added.
EDIT-2: Image added

Comment: Errr... why the downvote ?

Comment: I didn't give you the down vote, but you need to ask a question that others can reproduce by providing us with data or more information. What does "R is using .RData File saved in Working Directory then RStudio is not using this & using it from someplace else." mean?

Comment: @lmo: I have added more details. Is this better ? Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Rstudio has an options menu (under menu "Preferences" on a Mac), try setting these to something that suits you.

[image]

Comment: I want to put **`~`** in this box. Do you anyway to do that ? Thanks your comment helped me in clarifying that **Rstudio** is the culprit here !!